# Rails Validations, only integers for :price_in_cents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

validates_format_of :price_in_cents, :with =>

What is the regexp for this simple validation

Comment: Can you describe what you want it to match?

Comment: One would assume "only integers."

Comment: Match:  Should "007" match?  Should "5." match?  Should "-3" match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [validates_numericality_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002172) with only_integer, combined with positive numbers to represent price in pennies.

Answer (score 0):

`/[0-9]+/` Matches one or more integers, however there are better ways to do this (as seen in marklai's answer).